# Keyboard input over SSH to the raspberry pi3 with pynput function in python

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, raspberry-pi3, keyboard-events, pynput

I'm trying to control a small car toy using the raspberry pi 3 the SSH 
from my laptop.

The challenge I'm facing is, when I'm directly connected on RPi (mouse, 
keyboard and monitor plugged to the RPI) everything works well, but 
when I connect to RPi over the SSH connection, this is what I see as an 
output: Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""

The method I'm using to connect to my RPi is "ssh pi@"

Please can you advice me what to do next?

The sample code I'm using is shown below:

Thank you,
Johny 1984

```
    from pynput import keyboard
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

    def on_press(key):
        # DO SOMETHING

    def on_release(key):
        # DO SOMETHING

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

the way I connecting to RPI over SSH

```
ssh pi@(RPI_IP_ADDRESS)
```

The error with the bunch of text above:

```
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens pynput needs X and some other setup listed in their documentation. So I ended up using keyboard package https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ instead of pynput.keyboard.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427345/keyboard-monitoring-without-display

I modified his solution a bit so that I can exit from listening when escape key is pressed. Roughly something like this:

```
import keyboard
import time
#declaring it global so that it can be modified from function
global releaseListening
keepListening = True


def key_press(key):
  print(key.name)
  #if escape is pressed make listening false and exit 
  if key.name == "esc"
    keepListening = False

keyboard.on_press(key_press)

while keepListening :
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.`, Python 3.6, keyboard 0.13.5

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, and I could find a solution.

To make above work over ssh it is required to open /etc/ssh/sshd_config and uncomment the following lines if
they are commented:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

then on remote RPI type `echo $DISPLAY`. The result should be something like this:

```
localhost:10.0
```

when running/debugging your script, you should set env variable DISPLAY=result_of_echo_$DISPLAY

P.s Do not forget to connect via ssh using X server -> `ssh user@address -X`

Comment: I am also encountering this issue, and i did all of the above steps, however `echo $DISPLAY` does not return anything.